# How do I receive security updates?

Tags: updating, security

On my client(s) website,  I turned the update module *on*.  From time to time, they receive an error message on every page about a security update.  They complain about this message, and they don't want to see it, so I turn the module *off*.  I still want to keep up-to-date with all the security upgrades.  How do I make sure I receive security updates?  Is there a feed,  an email list?

Comment: The error message should not be shown in every page; as far as I remember, it's shown only on specific administrative pages. That means that if I am watching a node page, that error message doesn't appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All security announcements are posted to an email list as well. Once logged in, go to your user profile page and subscribe to the security newsletter on the Edit » My newsletters tab.

[image: Add security newsletter update]

You can also get rss feeds for [core](http://drupal.org/security/rss.xml), [contrib](http://drupal.org/security/contrib/rss.xml), or [public service announcements](http://drupal.org/security/psa/rss.xml).

Comment: This covers it, the only other method I know is http://twitter.com/#!/drupalsecurity

Answer (score 2):

I personnally prefer to let update status on and register my email in `admin/reports/updates/settings`. Being subscribed to the Drupal security list is a must do, but you will receive security updates for every module on drupal.org and after a while you may don't remember which module you have installed on you client website and miss one update or have to go to his website to find out.
So, activate update status, install [Disable Messages](http://drupal.org/project/disable_messages) to hide the status update warning, and put your email to receive updates only for theses modules. Also in some email provider you can receive email with the [plus (+) sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags) in the form of your_email+update_clientname@example.com then when you monitor various client website, you can filter the update regarding the "+".